# asp.net mvc 4 get visitors quantity

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm  looking for the best way to get quantity of my unique visitors on my asp.net mvc 4 web application.

I have found this method in [this link](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/log_parser_unique_visitors.htm)

There is this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT date, c-ip 
INTO tmp.txt 
FROM 'C:\LogFiles\web\ex*'
```

But I cannot find `C:\LogFiles\` directory.

Is this good method for my solution ?
If somebody knows better way please advice

Comment: Which version of IIS are you running? Looks like you are not providing the correct path for the IIS logs. Have a look at `http://www.loganalyzer.net/log-analysis/iis-log-files.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.google.com/analytics/, you will get a dashboard with very good stats.

Answer (score 0):

I have a default install/setup on my laptop and it's probably under c:\inetpub\logs